# Adding to a bound ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, observablecollection

I'm trying to add a person to a list of campers(people). I have bound the `ListView(GridView)` to the database and it displays all the names, ages, and grades. But now I'm trying to add a new person and add(display) him to the `ListView` along with everyone else. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have:  `ObservableCollection`

```
class BindingCamper
{  // This class assist in binding campers from listview to the textboxes on the camperspage
    public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers { get; private set; }

    public BindingCamper()
    {
        Campers = new ObservableCollection<Camper>();

    } 
}
```

Here is where I add the list of names to the listview:

```
       MainWindow _parentForm;

    public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers { get; private set; }

    public CampersPage(MainWindow parent)
    {
        _parentForm = parent;
        InitializeComponent();


        var bindMe = new BindingCamper();

        for (int i = 0; i < _parentForm.allCampers.Count; i++)
            bindMe.Campers.Add(new Camper { Name = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getName(), Ages = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getAge(), SchoolGrade = _parentForm.allCampers[i].getGrade() });
        DataContext = bindMe;
```

Here is where I add a new camper(person) and I'm trying to add him/her to the listview:

```
            String nameMe;
        nameMe = txtNewFirstName.Text ;
        int age;
        int grade;
        if (nameMe != "" && IsNumber(txtNewGrade.Text) && IsNumber(txtNewAge.Text))
        { 
            age = Convert.ToInt16(txtNewAge.Text);
            grade = Convert.ToInt16(txtNewGrade.Text);
            // Create New Camper


            Camper person = new Camper(age, grade, nameMe);

            _parentForm.allCampers.Add(person);
            //_parentForm.camperPage.listViewCampers.Items.Refresh();
            var bind = new BindingCamper();
          //  bind.Campers.Add(new Camper { Name = person.getName(), Ages = person.getAge(), SchoolGrade = person.getGrade() });
          //  _parentForm.camperPage.Campers.Add(new Camper { Name =  person.getName(), Ages = person.getAge(), SchoolGrade = person.getGrade() });

            Close();
```

Comment: Where do you store campers: in BindingCamper class or in ObservableCollection<Camper> Camper proeprty of CampersPage?

Comment: I'm pretty sure BindingCamper. The only way I can think of is when I create a new camper to add to the list, I need to refresh the listview to show him. You think maybe that could be a way and do you know how I can go about doing that. Almost having to refresh the database i guess. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't refresh the database to add camper:

```
Camper person = new Camper(age, grade, nameMe);
if TryAddToDatabase(person)
{
    bindMe.Campers.Add(person);
}
```

If `ListView` is bounded to bindMe.Campers it would refresh automatically and show new item. I also would recommend you completely read the [WPFTutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LearnWPFin14Days.html) so you won't do any extra work in the future.

Comment: @TMan: It's your methods where you should implement adding person to database. I.e. you haven't refresh all persons from databse due to it's more hard for perfomance than adding one person.